# php no envia correo mail()

Tags: php, phpmailer

Tengo un codigo php por medio del PHPmailer por el cual deseo enviar un correo de recuperación de contraseña, el correo dice que envia pero en mi bandeja de entrada no veo nada.

```
<?php 
include("connection.php");

date_default_timezone_set('Etc/UTC');
require('PHPMailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php');
$mail = new PHPMailer; 
$mail->isSMTP(); 
$mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';       
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;      
$mail->Username = 'ejemplo@gmail.com';   
$mail->Password = 'aqui tu password';                                                   
$mail->setFrom('ejemplo@gmail.com', 'gmail.com');
$mail->addAddress('ejemplo@gmail.com', 'Contact Message');     // Add a recipient
$mail->addAddress('ejemplo@gmail.com', 'Contact Message');     // Add a recipient
$mail->addReplyTo('ejemplo@gmail.com', 'gmail.com');
$mail->Subject = 'Contact fron website Hernandez Paiting';
$mail->IsHTML(true);
$mail->Subject = 'New Contact Message';

$mail->send();
$mail->SmtpClose();
if ( $mail->IsError() ) { 
    echo "Error: <" + $mail->ErrorInfo + " ><br /><br />";
}
else {
    if (headers_sent()){
         die('<script type="text/javascript">window.location.href="index.php";</script>');
    }else{
      header('Location: index.php');
      die();
    } 
}

if (isset($_POST["email"]) && !empty($_POST['email'])) {
    $email = trim($_POST['email']);
    $code = md5(uniqid(true));

    if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) === false ) {
        $checkmail = $connect->query("SELECT email FROM users WHERE email='$email'") or die(mysqli_error('Errorrrrrrr'));
        $count = mysqli_num_rows($checkmail);

        if ($count==1) {
            $to = $email;
            $subject = "Recuperar tu contraseña";
            $header = "Hernandez Paiting";
            $body = "Clickea en este link para recuperar tu contraseña: http://localhost/hernandez-painting/back-comentarios/chgpw.php?email=$email&code=$code";
            mail($to,$subject,$body);
         } 
         if($checkmail){
            echo "Se ha enviado un correo a tu email nuevo";
         }
         else{
            echo "Opps, correo no existe";
         }
    }
}

 ?>
```

Comment: Revisa la sintaxis [https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/examples/gmail.phps]

Comment: @Gustavo Gracias era un error en el path del sendmail!